# How to change the value of two dependent dropdown lists onload?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to do the following:

1. get the user's choice from database for the first dropdown menu.
2. present the corresponding choices of the user's category in the second menu (from 1).

I was able to do that with "mouseup" event property but this is not what I want. I want it to change immediately after the first menu change which is done exactly after opening the page, I tried "onload" property but it did not work. Here is my code:

Body:

```
//First menu
المؤهل:
  <select id="qualificationList" name="qualification" required>
      <option value="TM" <?php echo ($studentInfoSqlResultRow['qualification']=="TM")? "selected" : ""?>>التمهيدي</option>
        <option value="ET" <?php echo ($studentInfoSqlResultRow['qualification']=="ET")? "selected" : ""?>>ابتدائي</option>
   </select><br><br>
// Second menu
الفصل:
<select id="get_classes" name="regularClass"></select><br><br>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('[name="qualification"]').mouseup(function(){
        if( $('[name="qualification"]').val() !== 'ET'){
          $("#gradeDL").prop("disabled",true);
        } else {
          $("#gradeDL").prop("disabled",false);
        }
        var category = $('#qualificationList').val();
        var dataString = "category="+category;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "getClasses.php", // Name of the php files
          data: dataString,
          success: function(html)
          {
              $("#get_classes").html(html);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

***Edit:*** **I have solved the problem. I simply removed this line:**

```
$('[name="qualification"]').mouseup(function(){
```

Because I did not need an event to change the second menu so now it execute a function when the document is fully loaded which exactly what I want.
Thanks everyone and I hope this will help.

Comment: How many items are we talking? Can you preload it as JSON and use JS to switch it out?

Comment: 0 to N, depends on how many classes the school have in that category, the second question I'm not sure I got what u mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<select id="selectOne" name="selectOne" required>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<select id="selectTwo" name="selectTwo"></select>

<!-- Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var changeClassMenu = function() {
        $('select[name="selectTwo"').html('<option val="' + $('select[name="selectOne"]').val() + '">' + $('select[name="selectOne"] option:selected').text() + '</option>');
    };

    $(function() {
        changeClassMenu();

        $('select[name="selectOne"]').on('change', function() {
            changeClassMenu();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Edit: there was a syntax error in my original answer, it should work now.

Comment: It still does not change it immediately, I have to change the selected option in the first to make the second menu's choice appear.

Answer (score 0):

Prepoulate regularClass select depending upon the value of $studentInfoSqlResultRow['qualification'] and if further changes done it can be done by your code..

Simple solution..